# Unable to properly escape rules in KNIME

Tags: escaping, knime

I use a "table creator" to create a list of rules which are then fed to a "rule-based row splitter (dictionary)"

The rules are of the form:

```
$colname$="somevalue"    TRUE
```

I have created this setup multiple times already and it is working fine.
However, some of the string values I need to compare contain doublequotes. According to the official documentation, they need to be scaped using a backslash. I tried that in various permutations, but it always fails.

Error message:

```
ERROR Rule-based Row Splitter (Dictionary) 0:228      Execute failed: 
java.text.ParseException: Line: 306: Expected: =>
$value$="2\"" => TRUE
```

Rule formating, I've tried, all failed:

```
$col$=5"
$col$=5\"
$col$="5""
$col$="5\""
```

According to the docs, the last one should be the correct syntax but it also fails with the above error code. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer after a long discussion in the KNIME forums. Posting the answer here for completeness sake:

There are two problem cases here and the solution is to handle them separately, one by one.

**1) Your string contains doublequotes**:

This is forbidden by KNIME. Encapsulate your string in slashes like so:

```
$colname$ = /and she said: "hi"/
```

**2) Your string contains slashes**:

Surround your string with doublequotes like so:

```
$colname$ = "i need size 40 3/4"
```

If you have both mixed inside the same string, you need to use code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot escape with the strings in quote (`"`), but you can with Perl-like Strings, where the start-end symbol is the slash character (`/`), though there you do not need to escape the `"`. (You need to escape the `/` though with the `\` character, which also need to be escaped if you need that.)

Example:

```
$column1$ = /She said: "1\/2 is half", but in BASIC the integer division is denoted by \\/ => "match"
TRUE => "no match"
```

For the input (from **Table Creator**) `She said: "1/2 is half", but in BASIC the integer division is denoted by \` it will produce `match`

Edit: The [parser](https://github.com/knime/knime-javasnippet/blob/analytics-platform/3.7.0/org.knime.jsnippets/src/org/knime/base/node/rules/engine/BaseRuleParser.java#L148-L178) and the [grammar description](https://github.com/knime/knime-javasnippet/blob/analytics-platform/3.7.0/org.knime.jsnippets/src/org/knime/base/node/rules/engine/SimpleRuleParser.java#L84-L86) confirm these.